# Technical background when implementing custom fonts in iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

I have a question regarding the technical background on how custom fonts embedded into an iOS app are handled by the system.

Are the fonts handled inside the sandbox itself or are they still first added to iOS so that the app can use them? Here is the quote (**EDIT:** from the iOS 3.2 Documentation):

> Applications that want to use custom fonts can now include those fonts in their application bundle and register those fonts with the system by including the UIAppFonts key in their Info.plist file. The value of this key is an array of strings identifying the font files in the application’s bundle. When the system sees the key, it loads the specified fonts and makes them available to the application.

The reason for this question is the following. I want to use a custom font in my app but the license agreement states the following:

> c. Licensee may not install the Font in the operating system the App runs on.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're quoting, cite your sources: it helps people understand what you've looked at before asking your question on Stackoverflow.